# gson.fromJson(string) not parsing: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 432

Tags: android, json, gson

I've found a few similar issues here and on google, but nothing that seems to match my problem.

here is the JSON being returned from the server:

```
"{
\"user\":
    {\"user_id\":19,
    \"user_name\":\"John Doe\",
    \"user_token\":\"1412869773.19\",
    \"profile_pic\":\"https://graph.facebook.com/12345/picture?type=large\",
    \"number_of_creds\":650,
    \"level\":10,
    \"is_new_user\":false,
    \"is_display\":false,
    \"gender\":\"male\",
    \"zip\":\"05405\",
    \"age\":39,
    \"numberOfCreditsEarned\":0},
\"success\":true,
\"message\":\"\",
\"extraParameter\":null,
\"user_token\":null
}"
```

and here is the object I'm trying to map it to:

```
public class NetworkUserLoginResponseModel {
    public UserModel user;
    public Boolean success;
    public String message;  
    public String extraParameter;
    public String user_token;
}
```

is it because of the escapes on the quotes ()?

can I not map a JSON string with an embedded object?

TIA

Comment: Yes. Without quotes this should work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from quotes present in your server response, with the latter it's not a valid JSON.

To test JSON string you can use : [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

With no quotes, Gson will successfully parse JSON string into NetworkUserLoginResponseModel object

Comment: I had to remove the beginning and ending quotes and also the escapes (\)...then it parsed.  Thanks.